# How can I save my preferred DNS server address in an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-network

I've set up a lab of virtual machines on Azure, along with a virtual network and DNS Server/domain controller. I want to shut them down and de-provision them on a regular basis, so I'm not charged when I'm not using them.

Unfortunately, whenever I restart them, the preferred DN server address that I defined on each VM is reset to automatically obtain an address. This requires me to manually adjust these properties on the VMs. It appears that restarting/re-provisioning causes me to get brand new virtual network adapters with default settings. Indeed, the adapter name changes at every restart, e.g., Ethernet 1, Ethernet 2, Ethernet 3, etc.

Is there a better way for me to save this preferred DNS server information, or more easily restore it upon restart?

By the way, I read the answers to [a similar post, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837576/how-to-make-windows-dns-and-wins-settings-persist-in-an-azure-vm), but I'm not sure that I understand the answers provided or if they apply. When it comes to networks, I'm a bit of a newbie. Note that all of the servers in my lab are using the same subnet and cloud service. Perhaps this is part of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Virtual Network, and configure your preferred DNS settings in the VNet configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have this set up. Perhaps I'm missing a related setting?